# How in Querydsl for Spring Data JPA do I find those entitities that have at least one child satisfying several conditions?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have the following relationships as part of my model:

[image]

I am trying to use the Querydsl functionality in Spring Data JPA to find all engagements where the associated student has a tenancy in a given residence within a given date range. I tried the following to return the appropriate `BooleanExpression` that could be combined with others and supplied to `EngagementRepository.findAll()`:

```
public BooleanExpression inResidence(Residence residence, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
    final QTenancy tenancies = QEngagement.engagement.student.tenancies.any();
    return tenancies.residence.eq(residence)
        .and(tenancies.startDate.loe(endDate))
        .and(tenancies.endDate.goe(startDate));
}
```

However the resulting SQL contains independent EXISTS subqueries for each of the three conditions – residence, start date and end date; that is, as it stands each condition could be satisfied by a different tenancy when what I am after is for a qualifying tenancy to satisfy all three conditions. I realise I have probably misunderstood the purpose of `any()` and suspect that I need to make use of Querydsl's subqueries, but I am not quite sure how to, especially since some examples I have found are for version 3 and things appear to have changed in version 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I managed to come up with for using subqueries in Querydsl 4. The generated SQL has just one EXISTS subquery that tests all three conditions.

```
public BooleanExpression inResidence(Residence residence, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
    final QTenancy tenancy = QTenancy.tenancy;
    return QEngagement.engagement.student.tenancies.any().in(
        JPAExpressions.selectFrom(tenancy).where(
            tenancy.residence.eq(residence)
                .and(tenancy.startDate.loe(endDate))
                .and(tenancy.endDate.goe(startDate))
        )
    );
}
```